# How do I implement a VAE with another subnetwork that is only connected in the loss function through KL divergence in KERAS?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to implement a VAE that is a simplified version of the figure. The posterior net is an encoder and a decoder replaces the Unet portion. (That architecture is implemented in Tensorflow here https://github.com/SimonKohl/probabilistic_unet)
[architecture picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pGpi.png)

I want to learn a good representation of mu_posterior and sigma_posterior using another prior net as in the figure.  However when I try to implement this in Keras, the prior net does not show up in my model.summary() output.  The output of prior net is mu_prior and sigma_prior which appears in the loss function as a KL divergence term between the prior and posteriors.  In my understanding, having it appear in the loss term is enough to compute a gradient with respect to the prior net parameters, but why is the prior net disconnected from the network?

I also attached the code for my loss function and how I define the model

```
        def vae_loss(x, x_pred):
            x = K.flatten(x)
            x_pred = K.flatten(x_pred)
            xent_loss = img_rows * img_cols * metrics.binary_crossentropy(x, x_pred)
            kl_loss = 0.5 * K.sum(-1 + zprior_log_var - z_log_var + K.exp(z_log_var) / K.exp(zprior_log_var) + K.square(z_mean - zprior_mean) / K.exp(zprior_log_var), axis=-1)
            return xent_loss + kl_loss
```

```
        vae = Model(x, x_pred)        
        vae.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(), loss=vae_loss)
```

I have thought about using gradient tape instead but if prior net does not appear in the model/trainable parameters I don't think that will help.  I have also defined a submodel with mu_prior and sigma_prior as the output and use that in the loss function of the overall model but the submodel is still disconnected.

I have checked the TF implementation of probabilistic unet and to my understanding their prior network is only connected in the loss function through KL divergence with the posterior parameters and it works so how come a similar architecture doesn't work in Keras?